# Flash CS3 Mouse Event

Tags: actionscript-3

I wanted to make `menubar.handmove` visible whenever the mouse is out of the button.
However when I go over/click the buttons visibility will be false but will not return to true when I remove the mouse to the buttons.

What should I do?

```
stop();

menubar.play_but.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playgame);
menubar.intr_but.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overdown1);
menubar.play_but.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overdown);
menubar.intr_but.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, instruc);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, menu);

var mouseE:Boolean = false;

function playgame(e:MouseEvent):void {
gotoAndPlay(63);
mouseE=true;
}

function overdown(e:MouseEvent):void {
 mouseE=true;
}

function instruc(e:MouseEvent):void {
gotoAndPlay(64);
mouseE=true;
}

function overdown1(e:MouseEvent):void {
mouseE=true;
}

function menu(e:MouseEvent):void {

if(mouseE==false;){
menubar.handmove.visible=true;
}else{
menubar.handmove.visible=false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add this code to your existing code:

```
menubar.intr_but.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, moveout);
menubar.play_but.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, moveout);

function moveout(e:MouseEvent):void {
    mouseE=false;
}
```

Also remove character `;` to compile successfully. Has to be:

```
if(mouseE==false){
```